# Piping contents to docker image

Tags: docker

I am able to start the server and use the client as shown here...

start server instance

```
docker run -d --name some-clickhouse-server --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 yandex/clickhouse-server
```

connect to it from a native client

```
docker run -it --rm --link some-clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server
```

If I do not use docker, importing csv data is as easy as this...

`cat qv_stock_20160620035119.csv | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO stock FORMAT CSV";`

How do I pipe the cat contents to docker image?

Answer (score 2):

You can send data to a program running in a container as you would do to a program running on the host:

```
echo "hello" | docker run -i --rm ubuntu cat
```

(Outputs `hello` and exists)

In your case, this should work:

```
cat host-local_file.csv | docker run -i --rm \
  --link some-clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server \
  yandex/clickhouse-client \
  clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server \
    --query="INSERT INTO stock FORMAT CSV"
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, `--host` is a parameter for the application running in the container, not for the `docker run` command. I updated that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, although it's somewhat clumsy...

```
docker exec <container-name> bash -c "echo \"$(cat <local-file>)\" | <app-in-container>"
```

This assumes you have `/bin/bash` in your container image.

So in your case:

```
docker exec some-clickhouse-client bash -c "echo \"$(cat qv_stock_20160620035119.csv)\" | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO stock FORMAT CSV";"
```

Assuming you've already started the client container and named it `some-clickhouse-client`.